# how to get send response from ajax to script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

in this i am sending the values to adduser.php and after execution completed inserted id will send to index.php.please give the comments

index.php

```
$.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "adduser.php",  
                data: "name="+ name +"&email="+ email,  
                success: function(msg,usrid){  
                alert(msg);
}
})
```

adduser.php

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_login`(fname,email) VALUES('$fname','$email')");
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
echo '0';
echo $id;
```

contact.php

this response id can be user for next page url as like `window.location.href="contact.php?id=$id";`if any other option to pass the id value to contact.php

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are you echo '0'; there

Comment: i want to send adduser.php page $id value to contact.php

Comment: Do you want to pass the response id from adduser to contact.php, right?

Comment: correct sir.@JoseRojas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback in the AJAX request receive as argument the response, try this:

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "adduser.php",  
            data: "name="+ name +"&email="+ email,  
            success: function(usrid){  
                   window.location.href="contact.php?id="+usrid;
                }
})
```

the zero at your adduser.php is unnecessary.

Comment: How can i get values of two function variables like success: function(usrid,email){  
                   window.location.href="contact.php?id="+usrid;
                }

Comment: in the response at the server side you can echo the data as array encoding as JSON that way you can get from the server as many variables as you need, somthing like `echo json_encode(array('usrid' => 1, 'foo' => 'bar'));` at the client side, you can obtain this values `success: function(response){ response.usrid; response.foo }`